# Why does Array.constants not show the list of constants in Object class?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, constants

If I create:

```
class Test1
  A = 4
end

class Test2 < Test1
end
```

`Test2.constants` returns `[:A]` since it derives `A` from `Test1`. `Array.constants` is `[]` even though its superclass is `Object` and `Object.constants` has many values. How come `Array` does not derive those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All top level constants in Ruby are added to Object as you have seen with `Object.constants`. The advantage of this is that every class inherits from Object, so all top level constants are always available (as you might intuitively expect).

Now suppose that `Module#constants` worked as you expected: every class lists the top level constants it inherits from `Object`. What a pain that would be! We would constantly be writing `Foo.constants - Object.constants` meaning "the constants other than the uninteresting ones that are always around".

The Ruby designers thought of this headache and added a special exception to [`rb_mod_const_of`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/variable.c#L2025) - the C function used to walk up the inheritance chain and find constants:

```
if (tmp == rb_cObject && mod != rb_cObject) break;
```

I.e. if we've reached `Object` in the inheritance chain, and we aren't looking for the constants of `Object` itself, stop looking.

Comment: Not black magic, just plain old C code. Though you're right, understanding the Class/Module/Object inheritance chain is anything but easy :-)

Comment: If that is the case, then when you declare a new class Foo, where does the constant Foo reside in? I thought it would reside in the Object class just as any other constants you declare. And if Foo were to reside in the Object class, then Object.constants should really be returning that massive list you refer to including Foo

Comment: @user3727771 You're right about that. Upon further investigation, `Object.constants` is indeed calling the instance method. It is no longer clear to me why we don't see the full list of constants in every class. I'm currently digging through the C code to find out why.

Comment: @user3727771 edited with an actual answer. Thanks to jhass on the Ruby irc channel who actually found the snippet of C code.

Comment: thanks Max. That validates my theory that Object.constants were hidden from subclasses due to convenience and that all top level constants are indeed stored in Object